# pandas left join on column with list values

Tags: python, pandas

Giving this two Data samples, I would like to join by a column that in the left join dataframe the value is a list of one element of several and in the other dataframe is the same colum (primary key) with aditional information without list as format.

with this example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[[1111],[2222,3333],[4444,5555],[6666]],'NAME':['foo','bar','zoo','bahh']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[[1111],[2222],[3333],[4444],[5555],[7777]],'ALT_NAME':['foo_alt','bar_alt','zoo_alt','baoo','razz','foo fi']})
    print(df1)
    print(df2)
```

Output[1]:

```
    ID              NAME
0   [1111]          foo
1   [2222, 3333]    bar
2   [4444, 5555]    zoo
3   [6666]          bahh
```

Output[2]:

```
    ALT_NAME    ID
0   foo_alt     [1111]
1   bar_alt     [2222]
2   wis_alt     [3333]
3   baoo        [4444]
4   razz        [5555]
5   foo fi      [7777]
```

The result should be:

```
    ID              NAME    ALT NAME
0   [1111]          foo     [foo_alt]       
1   [2222, 3333]    bar     [bar_alt , wis_alt]
2   [4444, 5555]    zoo     [baoo, razz]        
3   [6666]          bahh    nan
```

## Proposed solution:

I could solve it by splitting the ID in several columns and do several left joins, but I expect finding onliner or smarter solution. So, The nature of this question is more python learning oriented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert your Ouput[2] to a map (a pandas series), e.g.:

```
df2.ID = df2.ID.apply(lambda x: x[0])
s2 = df2.set_index('ID')['ALT_NAME'] # let us rename it s2 as it is a series now!
```

When that is done you can simply use apply and fetch the values with a list comprehension:

```
df1['ALT NAME'] = df1.ID.apply(lambda x: [s2.get(i,None) for i in x])
print(df1)
```

Returns:

```
             ID  NAME            ALT NAME
0        [1111]   foo           [foo_alt]
1  [2222, 3333]   bar  [bar_alt, zoo_alt]
2  [4444, 5555]   zoo        [baoo, razz]
3        [6666]  bahh              [None]
```

---

**Small comment**: This does not give you the `nan` in last row. But what if you have 1 match and 1 none match, is that not [match1, None]?.

Df2 after conversion to s2:

```
ID
1111    foo_alt
2222    bar_alt
3333    zoo_alt
4444       baoo
5555       razz
7777     foo fi
```

one-row version: `s2 = df2.assign(ID=df2.ID.apply(lambda x: x[0])).set_index('ID')['ALT_NAME']`

Comment: you did it perfectly! , None inside a list or nonte by itself is indifferent, that None or [None] means for me: There wasnt any other avialiable name in the corresponding dataset

Comment: Trying to perform it, seems slow but expecting to have results

Comment: Yes unforrunately this isn’t very fast. Your frames are not optimal initially.

Answer (score 0):

I would just created additional column as string type and joined on it.

```
df1['ID_STR'] = df1['ID'].astype(str)
df2['ID_STR'] = df2['ID'].astype(str)

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = 'ID_STR')
```