# Merge two dataframe based on a list element matches in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

**df1**

```
Groups Value1 Value2 List_sp
G1     2      3      [Segment_1_1-300_+__Sp1, Segment_2_301-400_-__Sp2]
G1     4      5      [Segment_3_400-500_+__Sp3, Segment_2_600-700_+__Sp4]
G2     6      7      [Segment_12_800-900_-__Sp1]
G2     8      9      [Segment_1_400-500_-__Sp3, Segment_7_600-900_+__Sp1, Segment_15_1000-1900_-__Sp1]
```

and
**df2**

```
Groups sp 
G1 Segment_1_1-300_+__Sp1
G1 Segment_2_301-400_-__Sp2
G1 Segment_3_400-500_+__Sp3
G1 Segment_2_600-700_+__Sp4
G2 Segment_12_800-900_-__Sp1
G2 Segment_1_400-500_-__Sp3
G2 Segment_7_600-900_+__Sp1
G2 Segment_15_1000-1900_-__Sp1
```

And I would like to mege `df1` and `df2` based on the `df1['List_sp']` and `df2['sp']` elements.
Here are the expected results :

```
Expected results: 

Groups sp                       Value1 Value2 List_sp
G1 Segment_1_1-300_+__Sp1       2      3      [Segment_1_1-300_+__Sp1, Segment_2_301-400_-__Sp2]
G1 Segment_2_301-400_-__Sp2     2      3      [Segment_1_1-300_+__Sp1, Segment_2_301-400_-__Sp2]
G1 Segment_3_400-500_+__Sp3     4      5      [Segment_3_400-500_+__Sp3, Segment_2_600-700_+__Sp4]
G1 Segment_2_600-700_+__Sp4     4      5      [Segment_3_400-500_+__Sp3, Segment_2_600-700_+__Sp4]
G1 Segment_12_800-900_-__Sp1    6      7      [Segment_12_800-900_-__Sp1]
G2 Segment_1_400-500_-__Sp3     8      9      [Segment_1_400-500_-__Sp3, Segment_7_600-900_+__Sp1, Segment_15_1000-1900_-__Sp1]
G2 Segment_7_600-900_+__Sp1     8      9      [Segment_1_400-500_-__Sp3, Segment_7_600-900_+__Sp1, Segment_15_1000-1900_-__Sp1]
G2 Segment_15_1000-1900_-__Sp1  8      9      [Segment_1_400-500_-__Sp3, Segment_7_600-900_+__Sp1, Segment_15_1000-1900_-__Sp1]
```

If it can help here are the two dataframe in dictionnary format :

**df1**

```
{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G2', 6: 'G2', 7: 'G2'}, 'sp': {0: 'Segment_1_1-300_+__Sp1', 1: 'Segment_2_301-400_-__Sp2', 2: 'Segment_3_400-500_+__Sp3', 3: 'Segment_2_600-700_+__Sp4', 4: 'Segment_12_800-900_-__Sp1', 5: 'Segment_1_400-500_-__Sp3', 6: 'Segment_7_600-900_+__Sp1', 7: 'Segment_15_1000-1900_-__Sp1'}}
```

**df2**

```
{'Groups;sp': {0: 'G1;Segment_1_1-300_+__Sp1', 1: 'G1;Segment_2_301-400_-__Sp2', 2: 'G1;Segment_3_400-500_+__Sp3', 3: 'G1;Segment_2_600-700_+__Sp4', 4: 'G2;Segment_12_800-900_-__Sp1', 5: 'G2;Segment_1_400-500_-__Sp3', 6: 'G2;Segment_7_600-900_+__Sp1', 7: 'G2;Segment_15_1000-1900_-__Sp1'}}
```

Thanks a lot for your help and time

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536771/pandas-left-join-on-column-with-list-values

Comment: Why don't you merge via `Groups` because that's also same thing.

Comment: Because within groups the columns Value1 and Value2 change depending on the elements in List_sp

Comment: Don't you want `Groups` and `sp` from the second dataframe split into to individual columns? Per your dictionary formats, they're one column joined by `;`. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69885743/17242583) below does this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do `explode` first then we can `merge`

```
df1.List_sp = df1.List_sp.str.strip('[|]').str.split(', ')
# noted above is try to convert the string to list , if your original df already have list type , you can just go start with below 
df1['sp'] = df1.List_sp
out = df2.merge(df1.explode('sp'),how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```py
df2['Groups;sp'].str.split(';', expand=True).rename({0: 'Groups', 1: 'sp'}, axis=1).merge(df1, on='Groups')
```